# How to extract files from .tar archive with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, tar

Good day all,

I'm trying to get a tar.gz attachment from Gmail, extract the file and save it to Google Drive. It's a daily auto generated report which I'm getting, compressed due to >25mb raw size.

I got this so far:

```
  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Setup");

  var gmailLabels  = sheet.getRange("B2:B2").getValue();  //I have my Gmail Label stored here
  var driveFolder  = sheet.getRange("B5:B5").getValue();  //I have my GDrive folder name stored here

  // apply label filter, search only last 24hrs mail
  var filter = "has:attachment label:" + gmailLabels + " after:" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getTime()-1*(24*60*60*1000)), "GMT", "yyyy/MM/dd");

  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter, 0, 1); // check only 1 email at a time  

  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveFolder);

  if (folder.hasNext()) {
    folder = folder.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(driveFolder);
  }


    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];

    var desc   = message.getSubject() + " #" + message.getId();
    var att    = message.getAttachments();

    for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
      var attName = att[z].getName()
      var attExt = attName.search('csv')
      if (attExt > 0){ var fileType = "csv"; }
      else {
        var attExt = attName.search('tar.gz');
        if (attExt > 0){ var fileType = "gzip"; }
        else {
          threads[x].addLabel(skipLabel);  
          continue;
        }
      }

      // save the file to GDrive
      try {
        file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
        file.setDescription(desc);
      }
      catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
      }

      // extract if gzip
      if (fileType == 'gzip' ){
        var ungzippedFile = Utilities.ungzip(file);
        try {
          gz_file = folder.createFile(ungzippedFile);
          gz_file.setDescription(desc);
        }
        catch (e) {
          Logger.log(e.toString());
        }
      }

    }
```

Everything works fine, but in the last step it only decompresses the .gz file saving .tar file in the Drive. What can I do with it next? The .tar file contains a .csv file which I need to extract and process afterwards.

I should probably add that I'm limited to use GAS only.

Any help warmly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the `utilities` method like [`ungzip(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#ungzipblob)?

Comment: Yes, 11th line of the code from the bottom invoces Utilities.ungzip(). It extracts .gz file correctly but leaves me with a .tr archive after decompression which I have yet to find a way to deal with, hence the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this answer? Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for extracting files from a tar file in Google Apps Script, yet. But fortunately, from [wiki of tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)), we can retrieve the structure of the tar data. I implemented this method with Google Apps Script using this structure data.

### 1. Unarchive of tar data:

Before you run this script, please set the file ID of tar file to `run()`. Then, run `run()`.

#### Sample script:

```
function tarUnarchiver(blob) {
  var mimeType = blob.getContentType();
  if (!mimeType || !~mimeType.indexOf("application/x-tar")) {
    throw new Error("Inputted blob is not mimeType of tar. mimeType of inputted blob is " + mimeType);
  }
  var baseChunkSize = 512;
  var byte = blob.getBytes();
  var res = [];
  do {
    var headers = [];
    do {
      var chunk = byte.splice(0, baseChunkSize);
      var headerStruct = {
        filePath: function(b) {
          var r = [];
          for (var i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (b[i] != 0) {
              r = b.slice(0, i + 1);
              break;
            }
          }
          return r;
        }(chunk.slice(0, 100)),
        fileSize: chunk.slice(124, 124 + 11),
        fileType: Utilities.newBlob(chunk.slice(156, 156 + 1)).getDataAsString(),
      };
      Object.keys(headerStruct).forEach(function(e) {
        var t = Utilities.newBlob(headerStruct[e]).getDataAsString();
        if (e == "fileSize") t = parseInt(t, 8);
        headerStruct[e] = t;
      });
      headers.push(headerStruct);
    } while (headerStruct.fileType == "5");
    var lastHeader = headers[headers.length - 1];
    var filePath = lastHeader.filePath.split("/");
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(byte.splice(0, lastHeader.fileSize)).setName(filePath[filePath.length - 1]).setContentTypeFromExtension();
    byte.splice(0, Math.ceil(lastHeader.fileSize / baseChunkSize) * baseChunkSize - lastHeader.fileSize);
    res.push({fileInf: lastHeader, file: blob});
  } while (byte[0] != 0);
  return res;
}

// Following function is a sample script for using tarUnarchiver().
// Please modify this to your situation.
function run() {
  // When you want to extract the files from .tar.gz file, please use the following script.
  var id = "### file ID of .tar.gz file ###";
  var gz = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().setContentTypeFromExtension();
  var blob = Utilities.ungzip(gz).setContentTypeFromExtension();

  // When you want to extract the files from .tar file, please use the following script.
  var id = "### file ID of .tar file ###";
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().setContentType("application/x-tar");

  // Extract files from a tar data.
  var res = tarUnarchiver(blob);

  // If you want to create the extracted files to Google Drive, please use the following script.
  res.forEach(function(e) {
    DriveApp.createFile(e.file);
  });

  // You can see the file information by below script.
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

### 2. Modification of your script:

If this script is used for your script, for example, how about this? `tarUnarchiver()` of above script is used. But I'm not sure how you want to use this script. So please think of this as a sample.

#### Sample script:

```
// extract if gzip
if (fileType == 'gzip' ){
  var ungzippedFile = Utilities.ungzip(file);
  try {

    var blob = ungzippedFile.setContentType("application/x-tar"); // Added
    tarUnarchiver(blob).forEach(function(e) {folder.createFile(e.file)}); // Added

  }
  catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, the blob of `ungzippedFile` (tar data) is put to my script and run `tarUnarchiver()`. Then, each file is created to the folder.

#### Note:

- **When you run this script, if an error related to mimeType occurs, please set the mimeType of "tar" to the input blob.**

  - As the method for setting the mimeType, you can use as follows.

    - `blob.setContentTypeFromExtension()`  [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setContentTypeFromExtension())
    - `blob.setContentType("application/x-tar")`  [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypecontenttype)
  - It might have already been got the mimeType in the blob. At that time, `setContentTypeFromExtension()` and `setContentType()` are not required.
- If you want to retrieve the file path of each file, please check the response from `tarUnarchiver()`. You can see it as a property of `fileInf` from the response.

### Limitations:

When this script is used, there is the limitations as follows. These limitations are due to Google's specification.

- About the file size, when the size of tar data is over 50 MB (52,428,800 bytes), an error related to size limitation occurs.
- When the size of extracted file is over 50 MB, an error occurs.
- When a single file size of extracted file is near to 50 MB, there is a case that an error occurs.

  - In my environment, I could confirm that the size of 49 MB can be extracted. But in the case of just 50 MB
    , an error occurred.

### Reference:

- [tar (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing))

In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. But if this script didn't work, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample tar file? I would like to check it and modify the script.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I will test today afternoon and get back to you too confirm the results. Really appreciated!

Comment: just tested and it works great, many thanks for taking the time to write this function and share it!

Comment: @ErrHuman I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.